# How to access data from deeply nested child components in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building an interface using Vue.js.  I have a form, this form contains an address, and other bits of miscellaneous data.  So I created two components in Vue, `UserData` and `UserAddress`.  `UserData` contains an instance of `UserAddress` as a child component.  I want to specialize the behaviour of the "Submit" button for the form depending on the page, so these components don't contain the submit button -- the outer component, representing the page (`UserPage`) contains the submit button, and just includes the `UserData` template.

So the hierarchy goes, `UserPage` => `UserData` => `UserAddress`.

Now I need to get ALL the form data within some method on `UserPage`.  I would just say that I need to get it within the submit handler, but the only way that I can think to do this without directly accessing the data of the child components is the following:

- Use `$broadcast` to propagate an event `e1` downwards from the submit handler
- Listen for the `e1` event in `UserAddress`
- Use `$dispatch` to send an event `e2` and bundle the address data with the message
- Listen for `e2` in `UserData`, add the other form data to the message, and propagate or re-dispatch the event
- Listen for `e2` in `UserPage` and find the full aggregated data there.

Is this a normal method for dealing with a situation like this?  It seems like overkill, but accessing child `$data` is explicitly non-recommended by the manual.

Comment: Later I realized that dealing with this at all is insane.  Whenever you want to do this it's a sign that you should be using Vuex.  Also, events are gone in Vue 2.0, so don't rely on them.

Comment: events are not gone in 2, you just have to use a hub instead of broadcast and dispatch

Comment: Not gone, but marked as deprecated on the migration guide.  I experimented with the hub pattern, but it quickly got out of control.  Vuex is much better.

Answer (score 4):

Use `twoWay` props. If you declare `twoWay: true` in a child property, and pass a variable from the parent like `:child-prop.sync="parent-data"`, then the value of the property is written on the parent. You can make a chain with this. The code would be like this

**child**

```
<template>
  <input v-model="address">
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    address: {
      type: String,
      twoWay: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**parent**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="uname">
    <user-address :address.sync="uaddress"></user-address>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default () {
  components: {
    'user-address': userAddress
  },
  props: {
    uaddress: {
        type: String,
      twoWay: true
    },
    uname: {
        type: String,
      twoWay: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

check [**this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/p01dunw8/2/) with the chain `userPage` => `userData` => `userAddress`