# pass string to nested vue component and access it in nested component

Tags: php, vue.js

I have a vue component and it pass the string to nested vue component as follow,

```
<products-by-category :category="this.value"></products-by-category>
```

following section shows how I try to use that passed string in that nested vue component. but it is not getting that string to `<span>`. what is the wrong with it??

```
<template>
  <span>Category : {{ categories }}</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "ProductsByCategory",
  props: {
  category: {
    type: String,
    default: function (){
      return ''
    }
  }
  },

  data(){
   return {
     categories: this.category
   }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it as follows,

```
<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="category">
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "ProductsByCategory",
  props: {
  category: {
    type: String,
  }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

reference: [How to access data from deeply nested child components in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36499665/how-to-access-data-from-deeply-nested-child-components-in-vue-js)